# Texto e input en la misma línea y alineado a la derecha

Tags: html, css, select, entrada

estoy intentando que el texto y el input de varios label se queden en la misma linea, y alineandolos a la derecha. Soy nuevo en CSS y no lo consigo.

La idea es hacer algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div><label><span class="required">nif: </span></label>
<input type="text" name="nif" value=""  maxlength="9" required /></div>
```

gracias

Answer (score 3):

Para realizar este proceso es bastante sencillo con Flexbox, que también te invito a que investigues un poco más sobre las cajas flexibles te dejo un ejemplo de cómo puede ser un formulario estilo como la foto que mandaste.

espero sea de utilidad y responda tu pregunta.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Img/Favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.formulario {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 350px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.formulario .input-info {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.formulario input {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 5px;
}
        </style>
    <form action="#" class="formulario" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="input-info">
            <label class="info-label">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="input-info">
            <label class="info-label">Apellido:</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="input-info">
            <label class="info-label">Telefono:</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="input-info">
            <label class="info-label">Correo:</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: El texto de los `label` deberían estar alineados hacia la derecha, según la imagen del OP

Answer (score 1):

Un modo sencillo es alinear a la derecha los divs que contienen la etiqueta y el campo y darle un tamaño a los inputs para que sean iguales.

Puedes verlo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/jsu6z9d1/).

```
<div clase="item">
<span>nombre:</span>
<input type="text" name="nombre" class="finp">
</div>

//CSS
.item { text-align: right; }
.finp { width: 60%; }
```